# Jira create, edit log time for another user

Tags: jira

I need to create & edit logged time for tasks, for my teammates (in Jira) even if the user doesn’t have logged time yet.

It is possible ? In specific plan ? Via a plugin ?

I found nothing in settings (i'm pretty new in Jira utilization).

**Edit** : i found [the following plugin](https://www.tempo.io/tempo-timesheets-agile-time-tracking-plugin-for-jira). But i'm not sure if Jira have the feature for that need or not...

Comment: Question - why can't they do it themselves?

Comment: I move from clikcup and i want to relog the time for the current month already log in clickup for each user

Comment: Although we do accept some more "mundane" Jira questions as on-topic, I believe this one to be a bit too-specific / tool oriented so lending towards off-topic. Let's see what are the community perceptions.

Comment: @TiagoCardoso what is the best place to talk about Jira ? If i have futur question =) thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @Hadock - PM.SE has more than 250 questions tagged as [tag:Jira], so here _is_ a good place to ask your question. The challenge is that, you mentioned plugins... and it may lead to the [Shopping Cart](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) problem.